# How to get values from checkbox selections within a text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, each

I am trying to make a custom input, which will show multiple selections in an input. I partially have it working, but I cannot seem to figure out how to get multiple values to show in the `proposal-type` input. Whatever I choose, it only shows the value for A. Then if multiple selections are chosen, they do not appear.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

[Here is a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/p1jfojgr/)

```js
$('#proposal-type').click(function() {
  $('#proposal-type-drop').addClass('active');
});
$('.drop-item-input').on('change', function() {
  var typeVal = $('.drop-item-input').val();
  $('.drop-item-input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      console.log(typeVal);
      $('#proposal-type').val(typeVal).text(typeVal);
    };
  });
});
```

```css
#proposal-type-drop {
 width: 45%;
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
}
#proposal-type-drop.active {
 background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
 display: block;
 height: auto;
 z-index: 1;
}
.drop-item {
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: .9rem;
 padding: 5px;
 background: #000;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.drop-item-input {
 display: none;
}
.proposal-text {
 width: 95%;
 display: block;
 height: 6em;
 margin: 1.5% 2% 2.5% 2%; !important
}
#proposal-check {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-input">
  <input type="text" id="proposal-type" name="proposal_type" class="proposal-input" placeholder="Selection">
  <div id="proposal-type-drop">
    <label class="drop-item">A<input type="checkbox" class="drop-item-input" value="A"></label>
    <label class="drop-item">B<input type="checkbox" class="drop-item-input" value="B"></label>
    <label class="drop-item">C<input type="checkbox" class="drop-item-input" value="C"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `var typeVal = $('.drop-item-input').val();` searches for first '.drop-item-input', but you need current input, so change it to `var typeVal = $(this).val();`
and then in each callback concatenate all values: `typeVal += $(this).val()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.drop-item-input').on('change', function() {
  var proposalVal = "";
  $('.drop-item-input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    proposalVal += $(this).val();      
    };
    $('#proposal-type').val(proposalVal).text(proposalVal);
    $('#proposal-type-drop').removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Any idea, when looking at this: https://jsfiddle.net/p1jfojgr/2/ ... why the individual values aren't each getting a blue border? I am trying to get it so each look as tabs.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#proposal-type').click(function() 
{
   $('#proposal-type-drop').addClass('active');
});
$('.drop-item').click(function() 
{
  var seleVal = [];
  $('.drop-item-input').each(function()
    {
      if ($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
          seleVal.push($(this).val());
        }
    })
  $('#proposal-type').val(seleVal.join(','));
});
```

Comment: Here you will get comma separated value that and that you can process further. And on uncheck the value resets to the selected values.